# Wrap every occurrence of the text "Rs." with <span class="someClass">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have the currency "Rs." occurring on multiple places on my site. I want to wrap every occurrence of the text with `<span class="WebRupee">.` But if it is already wrapped with `<span class="WebRupee">` it should be ignored.

I cannot use `$('*:contains("Rs.")').wrap("<span class=\"WebRupee\");` because this wraps the html around the node that contains Rs. but not around the text alone. And for the same reason I cannot use `.wrapInner();`

Again any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT :** the javascript provided on the webrupee site doesn't work on my site(no clue why). So that's out of the question as a solution. And hence I thought of writing a custom javascript. Just don't know how I could approach this.

**EDIT(2):** thinking out loud - hmm is there a way to add html at the indexOf("Rs.") ..or a simmilar approach

Comment: It "doesn't work" so you immediately and completely write it off as a possible solution? No debugging? What if you got a single little configuration detail wrong? blimey...

Comment: thats the wierd part there are no errors thrown!.. i do my dugging on firebug ...but with out an error don't know where to begin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you are trying to do is a dirty hack.

You should fix it in the source, whatever it is (for example PHP backend, Ruby backend, plain HTML, etc...).

See this example working at http://jsfiddle.net/8jXLw/

I did many assumptions and simplifications, your Regular Expressions should be more complete.

```
var spanit = function(item) {
    var $item = jQuery(item);
    var regexp = /\d+ Rs\./;
    var text = $item.text();
    if (!regexp.test(text)) {
        return;
    }
    if ($item.has(".WebRupee").length) {
        return;
    }
    var new_text = text.replace(" Rs."," <span class='WebRupee'>Rs.</span>");
    $item.html(new_text);
};

jQuery(function() {
    $("p.test").each(function() {
        spanit(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree it is a dirty hack! And should be fixed in PHP .. But using the html symbol element - &#x20B9; works only if the client pc has support for that specific symbol(which would have been the best solution). For now this looks like the best solution i can think of.

Comment: but again it doesn seem to work on my page. It gives me an jquery error but i cant view the error on firebug coz it apears as a link and on clicking it ..it takes me to the illumination tab on firebug which you have to pay for

Answer (score 1):

Use http://cdn.webrupee.com/js file. it is working fine. i had used for one website.
If you want download and customize little..
thanks..

Comment: that was the first solution .. but it doesn't work.. at all! dont know why

Answer (score 0):

very inefficient solution

```
    var replaced = $("body").html().replace('Rs.','<span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span>');
    $('body').html(replaced);
    var replaced = $("body").html().replace('<span class="WebRupee"><span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span></span>','<span class="WebRupee">Rs.</span>');
    $('body').html(replaced);
```